# How to force kerberos to use in memory credential cache?

Tags: linux, ssh, kerberos, single-sign-on, mitkerberos

MIT Kerberos supports [multiple types](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-devel/doc/basic/ccache_def.html) of credential cache to store tickets
.

For example, if I want to use a persistent keyring per-user in kernel memory I can add the following to `krb5.conf`.

```
[libdefaults]
    default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}
```

One of the options is a ccache in process memory.

**How do I enable this option?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the linked document, the memory cache is using `MEMORY` keyword so the following should do the job:

```
 default_ccache_name = MEMORY:
```

But note that this type of `ccache` will be destroyed once the process exits. Note that `:` needs to be present, otherwise it will try to store the ticket in the file called `MEMORY` in current working directory.

Comment: Does this mean that when obtaining the TGT with `kinit <username>` the TGT is destroyed right after `kinit` terminates? As far as I know it only runs for like a second to obtain the TGT and then it exits. What's the usecase for such a ccache type?

Comment: I didn't try that, but from the manual it looks like that. If you have kerberos set up at hand, what is harder than try that? The manual talks about `kadmin`, which is separate "shell" taking administrative command, where it would make sense (unlike the `kinit` command which is useful for long-term tickets).

Comment: This method does not work! It just creates a file in the current working directory to `kinit` called: "MEMORY". It seems that the default ccache type is `FILE` and if no other recognised keyword is prepended it is assumed to be `FILE`.

Comment: Can you try with `MEMORY:` I don't have kerberos setup at hand.

Comment: Thank you! This indeed works. I couldn't edit answer to reflect this as there wasn't enough character changes, I will happily accept it when the answer gets updated.

Comment: I updated the answer.